# Functional testing with Golang

Tags: go, testing, functional-testing

I have a webservice written in Golang.

I need to refactor it because it is poorly written.

I have seen Golang works with the format `TestMethodName(t *testing.T)`. This is great for unit testing, but in my case, methods will change a lot because of the refactoring.

That's why I want to write functional testing, so that I can test each endpoint, and check that output has correct format, without being dependant of functions

How should I do it with Golang ?

Is there any framework that helps me with functional tests ? In another stack, like PHP / Laravel for instance, I can swap PostgreSQL with a SQLite, or In Memory testing, which is very practical for this kind of tests.

Comment: I don't see how the testing package "being great for unit testing" makes it unsuitable for functional tests.

Comment: as long as the input and output of functions does not change you can keep using the same tests

Comment: @Peter what I mean is to test each functions, without any dependencies, it is OK. But all my fonctions will move, so right now, I don't want to unit test, but rather test fonctionality that will not move. I don't know how to do that. I just began with Go, so maybe it is an easy answer

Comment: Just because the functions are often named `TestMethodName`, doesn't mean you must use that naming scheme, or can't test whatever you want. Look at any large go project, and you'll see tests of all sorts, at all levels of integration.

Comment: @JimB Ok, this is a good point

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro questions asking for framework/library recommendations are off-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you need help with something show us the code you've tried and explain what issues you've encountered (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Check this article out to get you started: https://blog.questionable.services/article/testing-http-handlers-go/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test your API endpoints by using `net/http/httptest` package and mocking external dependencies.

See example: https://golang.org/src/net/http/httptest/example_test.go